# Mutating a public variable in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coffeescript

I am using the google maps API, and trying to center the map at the users location. In coffeescript, I have:

```
lat = undefined
long = undefined
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (position) ->
      lat = position.coords.latitude
      long = position.coords.longitude
      return
alert(lat)
```

The alert(lat) will give me undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, therefore, you will need to call `alert(lat)` **inside** of the `getCurrentPosition` call.

```
lat = undefined
long = undefined
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (position) ->
      lat = position.coords.latitude
      long = position.coords.longitude
      alert(lat)
      return
```

Comment: What if I want to use the new lat/long outside of getCurrentPosition?

Comment: @ChrisWissmach, then you're out of luck. You have to handle everything once the async call is complete, and the only ways to do that are 1) inside the method itself, or 2) use a promise API.